# Trading Order Book updates and calculations

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm working on building a Level 2 OrderBook at work.

I'm using a Concurrent Dictionary to store the data for the bids and the ask separately.

I'm reading packet data using a UDP listener and after I process the packet I pass the update to the bid/ask dictionary to a Task.

This works fine and the updates happen fast but it seems clunky.

When I need to do any calculations on the Orderbook I have to lock it do the calculation which seems like a bad thing considering its a concurrent dictionary.  I feel like I'm slowing down everything which defeats the purpose.

How would you suggest I get around the locking issues and slowing down the updates to do a calculation on the data?

Sorry I can't post code as I'm currently out but I just can't stop thinking about how to solve this.

Comment: Why do you use lock since you use ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: If I need to tally the total volume of say the first 5 levels As I am.summing the values ad the Dictionary gets updated while I am summing the values get corrupted and my result value comes out some weird int.

Comment: Store data in a database like SQL server.

Comment: How did you solve it in the end? Any sample code you can post? Or maybe on github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design has reached its limitations of only using one data silo. Hence I recommend that the design be changed to accommodate two silos and a data manager.

The primary goal should be to do the calculation operations required in a timely but safe manner and then secondly concentrate on any data input which should be free not to be blocked.

---

In this design there are three threads, one manager and two data silos.

### Data Input

A thread for the `UDP listener` will store, [enqueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287262(v=vs.110).aspx) all incoming data into a [ConcurrentQueue Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx). That storage silo will handle the job of the *concurrency* needs of the data in a *FIFO* manner.

### Data Manager

The second thread runs a data manager singleton which will *smurf* ([TryDequeue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208(v=vs.110).aspx)) the data from the data input `ConcurrentQueue` over to the final silo. Since the incoming data is in a Queue one can *throttle* the total number of records to cross this virtual bridge to achieve a standard performance which can be measured/monitored.

### Final Data Silo (`Orderbook`)

The final thread for summing operations is where the data will ultimately reside. The data itself can be a standard dictionary which will be *locked* by either the Data Manager or the Summing process. One can then change the priority of access to favor the summing process over the data manager or visa versa; that will be dictated by the ultimate needs of the operation.

With that design the data input is unblocked and the summing operation has priority over data input in a measured manner.

Comment: can you please have a look at this? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161122/how-to-process-dependent-results-of-producer-consumer-queue-without-locking